# how i can Explode Group_Concat in foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Query MySQL**
here query to get the result for all users with *Group_concat*

```
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT
    results.StuID,
    subjects_d.SubjectID,
    exams.ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(results.ExamID,',',results.Exam1,',',results.Exam2,',',results.Exam3 ORDER BY results.ExamID  ASC) AS data
FROM
    results
LEFT JOIN
    users
ON 
    users.UID = results.StuID
LEFT JOIN
    subjects_d
ON
    subjects_d.SubID = results.Sub_ID
LEFT JOIN
    exams
ON 
    exams.ID = results.ExamID
WHERE 
    subjects_d.C_ID = 3
AND 
    subjects_d.SubjectID = 4
GROUP BY results.StuID");
$result->execute(array($classid, $subjectid));
$results = $result->fetchAll();
```

**This is Result from mysql**

PHP code

```
<?php foreach($results as $result) { ?>
    <?php echo '<pre>';print_r($result)?>
<?php } ?>
```

**print_r**

```
Array
(
    [StuID] => 70
    [0] => 70
    [SubjectID] => 4
    [1] => 4
    [ID] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [data] => 1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0
    [3] => 1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0
)
```

Now how I can explode this data array in foreach loop
**Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode data string with comma as delimiter in foreach loop.

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    // explode with comma 
    $data_array = explode(',',$result['data']);
 }
```